# Adding an indexed table view with sections from SQLite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, uitableview

I have a table view which is populated from data from an SQLite database. I would like to make the table an indexed table view with sections.

Can anybody suggest the best way to do this ? All the examples I can find use a plist which I am not using.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this [link](http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/uitableview-%E2%80%93-5-indexed-table-view/) may be helpful to you.

You have to store the values in an array like the above link